# Can I remove HVAC pipes after exposing the ceiling?

Tags: hvac, insulation, ceiling

I recently removed the drywall ceiling from my basement and have two related questions about removing the HVAC ducts/pipes.  Pictures attached here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNfdM.jpg

1.
Is it OK to remove the insulation from the ducts? I believe that this was put in place so air con/heat didn't escape into the ceiling when the drywall was in place. Now that the ceiling space is part of the room, it doesn't seem to be a problem.

2.
Is it alright to remove the vents and take the ducts all the way up to the main area? (Removing red X area, taking back to square red area). Same rationale - when the ceiling was in place, it couldn't vent into the ceiling space, but now there is no need to have it vent into the middle. Seems sound - just need to understand if there are air flow considerations/calculations that are needed.

[image]

Alternatively, removing the ducts all the way up until the edge of the room - I don't need it to vent into the center, from the side of the room would be fine now that the ceiling is open.

Comment: The insulation is to reduce temperature loss so that the heat/cold goes where directed by the vents. So, no eliminating the dry wall doesn't mean it's ok to remove the insulation.


For a ceiling vent in a basement, the middle of the room is best for evenly distributed heat / cold throughout the room. It’s unlikely you’ll cause major issues by moving it a few feet to the side (unless there’s a thermostat under it or another vent above etc).

But, I have to ask, why? It sounds like you intend to "unfinish" your basement and leave it that way. I'm missing the objective. So it's hard to answer.

Comment: You can remove the insulation, but It might not look good and may be noisey.  As for moving the register, as long as it's not near the return there's no problem.  Go for it man.  You're not going to kill anyone.  Worst case scenario is this room is 4 degrees cooler/warmer than your other rooms.